# C++11 Threads, is it valid code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am playing around with threads features of C++11. But the following code does not compile under both clang (3.5) and gcc (4.9.2).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void add(int& x) {
    x += 1;
}

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int x{ 5 };
    int y{ 8 };

    std::thread my_thread_1{ add, x };
    std::thread my_thread_2{ add, y };
    my_thread_1.join();
    my_thread_2.join();

    std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is it valid C++11?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's valid, but the thread class *copies* its arguments, so you can't use references directly. You have to use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to make it work:

```
std::thread my_thread_1{ add, std::ref(x) };
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that Bjarne Stroustrup book, "The C++ programming language, Fourth edition" makes this mistake on page 116. That's why I was very puzzled.

Comment: Should we add std::ref even for const reference ?

Comment: @InsideLoop Use `std::cref` for const reference, otherwise the arg will get copied. (Unless the compiler is somehow able to optimize that out, I guess)